# Can I put MariaDB's tmpdir inside it's datadir on Centos 6?

Tags: mariadb

We have separate disks on our Centos 6 machine

- A smaller one for our `/` and system folders,
- A larger one for `/home/mainuser`

Currently MariaDB has the settings

```
datadir=/home/mainuser/mysql
tmpdir=/tmp
```

We'd like to move the tmpdir to the larger disk. Is it OK to use `/home/mainuser/mysql/tmp` and put the tmpdir inside the datadir? What problems, if any, could arise?

Will MariaDB manage the files, and clean up? Or do we need a cron to empty it periodically?

Comment: For those attempting this on a not EOL distro like Centos7+, see systemd's [ProtectHome=false](https://mariadb.com/kb/en/systemd/#useful-systemd-options) for the mariadb service otherwise access to /home is denied. Centos 6 was pre-systemd afaik.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would, instead, set

```
 tmpdir = /home/mainuser/tmp
```

When doing any sort of admin stuff, this makes it clear that `/home/mainuser/tmp` is potentially "junk" while all of `/home/mainuser/mysql` is important.

Your approach might work, but it mixes the two.

Note that the OS (at least Linux) empties out `/tmp` when restarting the OS, but won't do the same for 'your' tmp.  So, there could be some kruft left in your tmp after crashes.